If John 1:1 is teaching that the "Logos/Word" is the spoken word are we not stating the obvious? Is not Gods' "word or words" already with Him?
John 1:1, "In the beginning was the Word." On what basis would anyone come to the conclusion this is referring to Gods spoken words?
Also notice Genesis 1:1 which literally says, "in beginning," which obviously refers to the creation of the heavens and the earth. Was not Gods "word or spoken words" or even His plan obviously with Him before time and space?

hi Mr.Bond - this might introduce a big topic. I wondered if (i) could you expand on how John 1:1 is developed into a teaching about the Word, or special definition of it. (ii) who does come to the conclusion and where (iii) is there assumed a distinction between (e.g.) spoken/thought/written words, words and pronouncements, words and logic... which Greek has on different terms than English

@FelixLXX I understand your questions but for me to do that I would have to answer my own question which I plan to do later.

What does the Greek word, ῥῆμα (rhéma, SG 4487) mean and how does that compare with the Greek word, λόγος (logos, SG 3056)?

@Dieter I already know the meaning of Strong's #4487 and #3056, so what's your point? John 1:1 is NOT saying anything about "God's word" or "words belonging to God." It says "In the beginning The Word was already existing." The Word has self existence here. Then it says, "And the Word was with the God" (article shown for clarity). So The Word is shown to exist in relation to The God contrary to those trying to make this "God's word or words." Simply stated, this is not calling "The Word" something that belongs to "The God," but rather quite clearly something that exists in relation to the God.

Good. Then you know that the two words cannot both mean the spoken word, right?

It is obviously true that "Logos" can and does mean (in some places) the spoken word.  There are many examples of this.  However, that fact does not alter another fact that Jesus was also given the title, "The Word" as in Rev 19.

@Dottard I totally agree with you that the spoken word is used in some places. My main focus is on John 1:1. This verse concerns itself with God's revelation of Himself to man. Just as words convey ideas so the "Logos/Word reveals who God is in this verse. 1 John 1:1, "What was from the beginning, what we have heard, what we have seen with our eyes, what we beheld and our hands handled concerning the Word of Life--vs2, and the life was manifested, and we have seen and bear witness and proclaim to you the eternal life,  which was "WITH" the Father and was manifested to us."

The idea that the first verse in John's gospel is teaching that the Word is the spoken word - God's words, from the beginning - is shown to be unfounded just a few verses further on. John says that this Word is a "him" who is alive (verse 4). He is also life and light. And John the Baptist came to bear witness of that Light, and:
"He was in the world..." the Light. A "he" (verse 10).
"He came unto his own..." people, some of whom received him (verses 11-12).
"To them he gave power... them that believed on his name" (verse 12).
The clincher is verses 14 to 17 where we are told, "And the Word was made flesh, and dwelt among us... the only begotten of the Father... John bare witness of him... This is he of whom I spake... he was before me... of his fulness have all we received... grace and truth came by Jesus Christ."
It just could not be any clearer. To grasp who (not 'what') this Word is, keep reading through to verse 17. He became flesh in the person of Jesus Christ.

The answer I give here overlaps with Anne's answer and tries to focus on that part of this question which asks, "On what basis would anyone come to the conclusion this  is referring to God's spoken word?"
In my notes, which I have not double checked, logos comes some 331 times and rhema 70 times in the NT. But often they are both translated "word". I think the spectrum of meaning of "word" is potentially confusing.
Words have these elements  to them. e.g., the word "word"
can be a sound when spoken
or a shape when written
or a meaning when understood.
Matthew 12:36 ESV

"every careless word". word/rhema/single

A sound but empty of real meaning. [Empty milk bottle]
John 3:34

"utters the the words of God". words/rhemata/ plural

God's words uttered, sounded, and full of meaning. [ Full milk bottles]
Matthew 12:37

"for by your words you will be justified, and by your words you will be condemned". words/logon/plural

The outside sound and shape of our words may be important but what really matters is the inner meaning, and it is by that inner meaning that we will be  judged.
1 Thessalonians 2:13

"you received the word of God, which you heard from us....which is at work in you belivers". word/logon

Paul spoke and the inner meaning of his God given word is "at  work", changing the lives of believers.
1 John 4:14

"And we have seen and testify that the Father has sent his Son to be the Savior of the world".

The Word became flesh. The Father sent/spoke out His Son/Word.
The word "word" in the NT has a spectrum of meaning that goes from:
careless words; to sounds full of meaning; to [logio] many meanings or [logos]  just one meaning; to the ultimate meaning from which all other meanings are derived-i.e.,

"the word of life-made manifest- the eternal life which was with the Father." from 1 John 1-3. word/logou

In John 1:1 logos is the Son sent by the Father.
